# Cleaning up Data using a VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic request. Yet I can't seem to find anything on here that really helps me.

I'm trying to do some basic data clean up. I'm very new at VBA. So I recorded a macro that cleans up the data for me.

However it's for thousands of rows of data, and my macro only works on the first few rows. I've created a basic form of what my data looks like.

```
Range("A8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A17").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("D3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I'd like this to continue working. This is the example format for my data.
Name/Comments/Date/Cost <- Header columns

The following data is all in the same 'A' column.

```
john

Hello

9/12/1999

62


Tim

Yup

9/13/1999

623

Betty

Right on

9/14/1999

52
```

Thanks for any help on this.
~Signed~
The VBA Noob

Comment: What criteria are you using to select certain cells to copy and paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I've assumed that you have data that is vertically populated straight down in column A starting at cell A2 and ending at cell A13 in your sample data.  And you need that data transposed horizontally in groups of 4 such that:

- cells A6:A9 will be moved to B2:B5
- cells A10:A13 will be moved to C2:C5
- cells A14:A17 will be moved to D2:D5
- etc....

If that is the correct assumption, then replace the code in your existing macro with the following, being sure to change the cell address for the 'lastCellInColumn' variable as needed:

```
Dim firstCellInDataColumn As Range
Dim lastCellInDataColumn As Range
Dim destinationCell As Range
Dim rowsPerDataGroup As Integer
Dim positionInGroup As Integer
Dim destinationRowOffset As Integer
Dim destinationColumnOffset As Integer

'initialize first source cell, set destination cell to the cell adjacent right
Set firstCellInDataColumn = Range("A2")
Set lastCellInDataColumn = Range("A13")
Set destinationCell = Range(firstCellInDataColumn.Offset(0, 1).Address)

rowsPerDataGroup = 4 'number of data points in each dataset
positionInGroup = 1 'counter to keep track of position within the group
destinationRowOffset = 1
destinationColumnOffset = 0

'loop through all cells in the column
For Each cell In Range(firstCellInDataColumn, lastCellInDataColumn)
    destinationCell.Value = cell.Value
    If positionInGroup = rowsPerDataGroup Then 'start new destination column
        positionInGroup = 1
        destinationRowOffset = 1
        destinationColumnOffset = -3
    Else
        positionInGroup = positionInGroup + 1
        destinationRowOffset = 0
        destinationColumnOffset = 1
    End If
    Set destinationCell = Range(destinationCell.Offset(destinationRowOffset, destinationColumnOffset).Address)
Next cell

Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: Hey Capt_Krunch, that is soooo close. I was trying to move cells A6:A9 will be moved to A2:D2
cells A10:A13 will be moved to A3:D3
cells A14:A17 will be moved to A4:D4 and so on...

Comment: Moving those 4 vertical data points in column A; horizontally on a row.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have modified the code accordingly.  Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You are my hero and have saved me hours of time. I can't thank you enough. I'm slowly learning VBA and realizing how useful it is to all of my excel work. Thanks again!